# the diffence between references_many and has_many in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reference, mongoid

I am new to mongoid. i start doing mongoid with rubyonrails with help of screen cast #238 of Ryan bate.

I found in the section of "Reference" of mongoid official website describing about the has_many.

Can anyone help me to explain what is the difference between has_many and references_many and which version of mongoid support them.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: They are aliases, there is no difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From mongoid doc you can read this :

http://mongoid.org/docs/upgrading.html

> Relational associations no longer autosave when the parent relation is
>   created. Previously a save on a new document which had a
>   references_many or references_one association loaded would save the
>   relations on it's first save. In order to get this functionality back,
>   an autosave: true option must be provided to the macro (This only
>   applies to references_many and references_one):

So now I think there is no differences and you can fill free to use `has_many` with options `autosave: true` if you need to :)